# How to get github users from city using Github REST API?

Tags: rest, github

### Background

I am working on an app and I need to get all the projects of all github users that live in a given city using the GitHub Rest API v3: https://developer.github.com/v3/

### Research

Now I know I can get all the users with the following url: 
https://api.github.com/users

And once I have a user, I can get all his repos and info from there.

### Problem

The problem is that I don't know how to filter those users by city!
I have tried adding a paramter `location=London` but it always returns the same, probably because this is not the real parameter...

Another option would be to get all the github users from the world, and then filter them by city .... which would be totally insane.

The best option I found so far was to use this link:

https://github.com/search?q=language:javascript+location:Barcelona&type=Users

However, this link is the web version, which does not use the REST API.

### Question

How do I get all the users from a given city using the Github REST API?

Comment: It looks like you want [`location`](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-users/#search-by-location), not `city`.

Comment: Same issue. If I could just convert the `github.com` link to use the API instead I would be ready to go...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the [`/users`](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/) endpoint.  You need to use the [`/search/users`](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users) endpoint:

```
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location%3Aiceland
```

Will search for users located in Iceland

Using that gets me a response with a bunch of users and after cross checking the first 3, they all have their location set to "Iceland" in their profiles.